# Parse a string with variable key value pairs

Tags: java, string, parsing

I have a string like this:

```
*********** name: NOTINSTATE timestamp: 2015-09-16T12:33:01.253Z 
MyKeyValue1 = myData MyKeyValue2 = 0.0 based on filter: no Filter
********************************
```

In this String i have the KeyValuePairs:

```
"name" NOTINSTATE
"timestamp" 2015-09-16T12:33:01.253Z
"MyKeyValue1" myData
"MyKeyValue2" 0.0
"based on filter" no Filter
```

I was thinking about something like Freemarker in reverse way but i don't think that Freemarker others this functionality.

I know i could do it on a dirty way and work with pattern and split the String but there must be a better way to do this.

Any suggestions or frameworks which would be useful?
My searchString itself will not be changed in the future. It will be always the same.

Comment: The values are obviously variable, but are the keys variable? All of them?

Comment: Nope the keys are always the same.

Comment: I was think about using some regex where i can say what is between two patterns to get my value. But i would have to do it for very value. This would be the dirty way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular expression is your friend:

```
String input = "*********** name: NOTINSTATE timestamp: 2015-09-16T12:33:01.253Z\n" +
               "MyKeyValue1 = myData MyKeyValue2 = 0.0 based on filter: no Filter\n" +
               "********************************";
String regex = "\\*+\\s+" +
               "(name):\\s+(.*?)\\s+" +
               "(timestamp):\\s+(.*?)\\s*[\r\n]+" +
               "(MyKeyValue1)\\s+=\\s+([^=]*)\\s+" +
               "(MyKeyValue2)\\s+=\\s+([^=]*)\\s+" +
               "(based on filter):\\s+(.*?)\\s*[\r\n]+" +
               "\\*+";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
if (m.matches()) {
    Map<String, String> pairs = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i += 2)
        pairs.put(m.group(i), m.group(i + 1));

    // print for testing
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : pairs.entrySet())
        System.out.printf("\"%s\" %s%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Output is exactly what you showed:

```
"name" NOTINSTATE
"timestamp" 2015-09-16T12:33:01.253Z
"MyKeyValue1" myData
"MyKeyValue2" 0.0
"based on filter" no Filter
```

**Update**

The above regex is lenient on spaces, but strict on key names. You could go strict on spaces and lenient on key names, or any other combination:

```
String regex = "\\*+ " +
               "(\\w+): (.+?) " +
               "(\\w+): (.+?)[\r\n]+" +
               "(\\w+) = ([^=]+?) " +
               "(\\w+) = ([^=]+?) " +
               "([^:]+): (.+?)[\r\n]+" +
               "\\*+";
```

Comment: I was thinking about regex but not a regex string to get all the value's. I have to do more with regex.